# r row names selection using columns

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

Suppose i have this matrix

```
 
      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 98 183 385 419 420 422 423 469 470 35698 35709 35729 37415
0     0 1 1 1 0 0 1  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0     0     0     0     1
1     1 0 1 0 0 1 1  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0     0     0     0     0
2     1 1 0 1 1 0 0  0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0     0     0     0     0
3     1 0 1 0 1 1 0  1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   0     1     0     0     1
4     0 0 1 1 0 1 1  1   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   1     0     1     1     0
5     0 1 0 1 1 0 1  1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1     0     0     1     0
6     1 1 0 0 1 1 0  1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     0
98    0 0 0 1 1 1 1  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1     0     0     1     0
183   0 0 0 1 0 0 0  0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0     0     0     0     1
385   1 1 0 0 0 0 1  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     0
419   0 0 1 1 1 0 0  0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0     1     1     0     0
420   0 0 0 1 1 1 0  1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     1     1     0     0
422   0 0 1 1 1 0 0  0   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   0     0     0     0     1
423   0 0 0 1 0 0 0  0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0     0     0     0     1
469   1 1 1 0 0 0 0  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0     0     0     0     1
470   0 0 0 0 1 1 0  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     1     0
35698 0 0 0 1 0 0 0  0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     0
35709 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     0
35729 0 0 0 0 1 1 0  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1     0     0     0     0
37415 1 0 0 1 0 0 0  0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0     0     0     0     0
```

I am getting a value from another program let us say
x=3.

I want to choose the name of rows where x == 1 i.e. where the value of 3 is 1.

Output will be : 0,2,4,5,98,183,419,420,422,423,35698,37415.
 And I don't want to pass "3" directly into the command. I want to pass the variable x so that if this number varies I could get the output accordingly.

Can anyone help me, please? thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide your expected output? I'm confused as to what exactly you're looking for.

Comment: Assuming you want the rows where the column named `'3'` is equal to 1, `rownames(this_matrix)[this_matrix[, '3'] == 1]`.

Comment: Is this matrix being created using the `matrix` command?

Comment: I just edited the question. Hopefully, it makes it more clear.

Comment: @Gregor it worked thanks a lot.

Comment: Just make sure what you pass is always a *character* object. If `x = 3`, `this_matrix[, x]` is the third column, `this_matrix[, as.character(x)]` is the column named 3.

Answer (score 1):

```
x=matrix(c(1,1,2,5,6,6,5,7,7,8,3,3,1,9,20,20,4,7,9,5),4,5,dimnames = list(c(letters[1:4]),c(LETTERS[1:5])))
```

you'r requirement is row names then

```
rownames(x)[x[,"D"]==20]
```

here '20' is you'r input value and D is you'r searching column.